# Solr 8.1 startup error - maxBooleanClauses

Tags: java, solr, server, solrj

We've upgraded our Solr version from 7.6.0 to 8.1 and started seeing the following on the server startup:

```
2019-05-29 16:18:28.475 ERROR (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown configuration value in solr.xml: maxBooleanClauses
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrXmlConfig.fillSolrSection(SolrXmlConfig.java:279)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrXmlConfig.fromConfig(SolrXmlConfig.java:109)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrXmlConfig.fromInputStream(SolrXmlConfig.java:140)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrXmlConfig.fromFile(SolrXmlConfig.java:122)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrXmlConfig.fromSolrHome(SolrXmlConfig.java:150)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.loadNodeConfig(SolrDispatchFilter.java:284)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.createCoreContainer(SolrDispatchFilter.java:250)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:750)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:744)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:453)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:579)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:415)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1572)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:490)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
```

What can be causing this and how can we fix it?  Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: Did you copied the solrconfig.xml as it from 7.6 to 8.1? Because in the new version it is mentioned as " <maxBooleanClauses>${solr.max.booleanClauses:1024}</maxBooleanClauses>" in the solrConfig.xml and in the solr.xml as "<int name="maxBooleanClauses">${solr.max.booleanClauses:1024}</int>"

Comment: I think the you need to remove the variable and just mention the number or copy the new solrConfig.xml and make the changes accordingly

Comment: if you have created a core and if is has its own configset then need to modify solrCOnfig.xml inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the old Solr jars were put by the build script into the solr web-app lib folder thus forcing Solr server to start the 7.6.0 version.  Kudos go to a coworker noticing the discrepancy by closely examining Solr log file.